# Is there a Bash function that allow me to separate/delete/isolate line from a file when they have the same first word

Tags: bash, filter, character, line

I have a text file like this:

```
id ; lorem ipsum  fgdg df gdg
id ; lorem ipsum  fgdg df gdg
id ; lorem ipsum  fgdg df gdg
id ; lorem ipsum  fgdg df gdg
id ; lorem ipsum  fgdg df gdg
```

And if 2 id are similar, I want to separate to line where 2 id are similar and the line that are unique.

`uniquefile` contains the lines with unique id.
`notuniquefile` contains the lines that don't have one.

I already found a way to almost do it but only with the first word. Basically it is just isolating the id and deleting the rest of line.

Command 1: isolating unique id (but missing the line):

```
awk -F ";" '{!seen[$1]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i }' originfile >> uniquefile
```

Command 2: isolating the not unique id (but missing the line and losing the "lorem ipsum" content that can be different depending on the line):

```
awk -F ":" '{!seen[$1]++;!ligne$0};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]>1)print i  }' originfile >> notuniquefile
```

So in a perfect world I would like you to help me obtain this type of result:

`originfile`:

```
1 ; toto
2 ; toto
3 ; toto
3 ; titi
4 ; titi
```

`uniquefile`:

```
1 ; toto
2 ; toto
4 ; titi
```

`notuniquefile`:

```
3 ; toto
3 ; titi
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Are only consecutive lines with equal `id` candidates for the `notunique` file?  If the line `4 ; titi` would have been a `1 ; titi` would it have been a non-unique in your usecase because of the `1 ; toto` in the first line?

Comment: I am not aware of a simple unix tool doing exactly what you need.  Maybe if you tell us more about your situation (what do you need it for?) we can figure out a different approach to solve your issue (this often happens).  See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: no for exemple if line 3 and line 20 have the same id they have to go in the not unique file.     
And the "titi , toto" , only the id have to be the filter

Comment: i already tryed to simplify my problembut here is a more simple approch to it :
file contains text like " id ; random text "

if 2 id are the same on different lines i have to know who they are ( i need the full information "id ; randomtext"

the rest of the ID that are unique, i also need to identify them clearly              "id ; randomtext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another method with just two unix commands, that works if your id fields always have the same length (let's assume they are one character in length like in my testdata, but it of course works also for longer fields):

```
# feed the testfile.txt sorted to uniq
# -w means: only compare the first 1 character of each line
# -D means: output only duplicate lines (fully not just one per group)
sort testfile.txt | uniq -w 1 -D > duplicates.txt

# then filter out all duplicate lines from the text file
# to just let the unique files slip through
# -v means: negate the pattern
# -F means: use fixed strings instead of regex
# -f means: load the patterns from a file
grep -v -F -f duplicates.txt testfile.txt > unique.txt
```

And the output is (for the same input lines as used in my other post):

```
$uniq -w 2 -D  testfile.txt 
2;line B
2;line C
3;line D
3;line E
3;line F
```

and:

```
$ grep -v -F -f duplicates.txt testfile.txt 
1;line A
4;line G
```

Btw. in case you want to avoid the `grep`, you can also store the output of the sort (lets say in sorted_file.txt) and replace the second line by

```
uniq -w 1 -u sorted_file.txt > unique.txt
```

where the number behind `-w` again is the length of your id field in characters.

Comment: thx, i did it like this :
sort test | uniq -w 12 -D > testNegatif
sort test | uniq -w 12 -u > testPositif

Comment: If you like, you can switch a `tee` inbetween the first line, so you don't need to sort twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small Python script which does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

unique_markers = []
unique_lines = []
nonunique_markers = set()
for line in sys.stdin:
  marker = line.split(' ')[0]
  if marker in nonunique_markers:
    # found a line which is not unique
    print(line, end='', file=sys.stderr)
  elif marker in unique_markers:
    # found a double
    index = unique_markers.index(marker)
    print(unique_lines[index], end='', file=sys.stderr)
    print(line, end='', file=sys.stderr)
    del unique_markers[index]
    del unique_lines[index]
    nonunique_markers.add(marker)
  else:
    # marker not known yet
    unique_markers.append(marker)
    unique_lines.append(line)
for line in unique_lines:
  print(line, end='', file=sys.stdout)
```

It is not a pure shell solution (which would be cumbersome and hard to maintain IMHO), but maybe it helps you.

Call it like this:

`separate_uniq.py < original.txt > uniq.txt 2> nonuniq.txt`

Comment: Hi Odran, no need to write thank-you comments.  Please use the upvote-button (upward triangle left of the answer) in case the answer was helpful to you.  Use the accept button (checkmark left of the answer) in case you feel the answer solved your issue.

Comment: i know but i can green chek only one comment and i can't upvote in need 15 karma they said ^^

Comment: Oh, yeah, special StackOverflow rules for newbies.  I guess they make sense somehow, though …

Answer (score 0):

untested: process the file twice: first to count the ids, second to decide where to print the record:

```
awk -F';' '
    NR == FNR      {count[$1]++; next}
    count[$1] == 1 {print > "uniquefile"}
    count[$1]  > 1 {print > "nonuniquefile"}
' file file
```

Comment: In my tests, it put everything in the file `uniquefile`.  Try the input `a foo`, `b bar`, `a foobar`.

Comment: The input file is semicolon-separated. That's what the `-F` option is for.

Comment: little rectification, it work for small number of line but when it got to high it seems like the print function have a limited size that he can print have once

Answer (score 0):

With a pure bash script, you could do it like this:

```
duplicate_file="duplicates.txt"
unique_file="unique.txt"
file="${unique_file}"
rm $duplicate_file $unique_file
last_id=""
cat testfile.txt | sort | ( 
    while IFS=";" read id line ; do
      echo $id
      if [[ "${last_id}" != "" ]] ; then
          if [[ "${last_id}" != "${id}" ]] ; then
             echo "${last_id};${last_line}" >> "${file}"
             file="${unique_file}"
          else
             file="${duplicate_file}"
             echo "${last_id};${last_line}" >> "${file}"
          fi
      fi
      last_line="${line}"
      last_id="${id}"
    done
    echo "${last_id};${last_line}" >> "${file}"
)
```

With an inputfile as:

```
1;line A
2;line B
2;line C
3;line D
3;line E
3;line F
4;line G
```

It outputs:

```
$ cat duplicates.txt 
2;line B
2;line C
3;line D
3;line E
3;line F
work$ cat unique.txt 
1;line A
4;line G
```